# Auto-Return to Site After Payment

Tags: paypal, return, payment, gateway

We are using a classic PayPal payment gateway method. At the end of the payment the user has to click on the return link (circled below) to return to our site with their payment info. If they do not click on the link, the payment information is never returned to our site. How can we automatically re-direct the user back to our site?

BTW We are also using the &return= as well as the auto-return page setting on the PayPal setup page - but no luck. The return page requires a user to be logged in (it checks for the user session on load).

[image: PayPal end screen]

Answer (score 0):

If the buyer is paying with a credit card, you can not automatically return them back to your site.  They are given time to write the information down, or print a copy of the page.  Then they have to click the button to return back to your site.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The problem for us is that sometimes the user does not click on the return link because it is not so obvious that they need to do it (even though we mention it to them prior to redirection to PayPal).Is there a way to make it more obvious, for example by using a button instead that stands out?

Comment: So we never get a success response back for the payment in these situations and their account has to be manually upgraded at a later time, which can be confusing for the user who is expecting an instant upgrade. Also is there a way to query PayPal on return to know if they were upgraded (we are not using Express Checkout but an older payment solution).

Comment: BTW Ijust checked and we are using the PayPal 'Website Payments Standard' solution.